# Clojure Luminus migratus db/schema file

Tags: clojure, luminus

I'm a new guy from RoR to Clojure/Luminus. After reading the book "web development with clojure", I find a question about DB migration. In Rails, after running a migration file, the newly modified table structure will show in the `db/schema.rb` file, so that we know what we defined for a table in the `schema` file. So I wondered if there is a file in Luminus similar to the `db/schema.rb`?

Comment: Migratus does not support such schema generation natively (and I can't think of anything but something like `pg_dump --schema-only <dbname>` - if you are using postgres), but I would be happy to know if there are any third-party libraries for that.

Comment: I'd like to know if there's some third-party lib for the `schema` too :)